# Xbindkeys: Execute command in current terminal

Tags: bash, xbindkeys

Is there a way to, instead of executing the command in the foreground, execute a command via Xbindkeys in the current Terminal? Similar to just pasting the command and pressing enter.

Comment: Is the issue that when you use your xbindkey the command is just run and you want it to run in your current terminal window? It would help if you show what the relevant xbindkey configuration entry is and what the expected outcome of the key press should do. Thank you.

Comment: The Idea is that when i press a certain key (Ctrl+Alt+N) a script (with a dialog) should be pasted in the currently open terminal and executed. The command has sort of a gui and needs user interaction, thus needs to launch in the current terminal.